# Visual Studio 2015 bogus compiler errors in F# .NET Core projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, f#, .net-core

If I create a .NET Core project (`dotnet new -l f# -t lib`) and code two `.fs` files, one of which contains code that depends on a type defined in the other, then I see "red underlining" real-time compiler errors in the dependent file, even if the code compiles just fine.

The ordering of the source files in the Solution Explorer isn't the issue, and I have the requisite `"compile":` section defined in `project.json`.  Again, the code compiles successfully.

Is there some way to lend Visual Studio a clue, so I'm not writing code with bogus red marks all over it?

Comment: Haven't ever used `project.json` (and now they've moved away from it again, so I'm not likely to ever use it). But one suggestion would be to look for the `.suo` file for your project (`.suo` stands for "Solution User Options", but it's basically a cache) and delete it, since I've heard of some cases where the `.suo` file persisted incorrect project information. [This blog](http://briannoyesblog.azurewebsites.net/2008/05/10/the-evil-suo-file-fighting-and-winning-with-visual-studio/) suggests that that might help. (Close VS first, then delete the `.suo` file, then reopen VS).

Comment: Is there an alternative to project.json for .NET Core projects in VS 2015?